# go back to old fragmnet from tablayout fragment on back press

Tags: android, fragment, android-tablayout, onbackpressed

I have fragment name is mainfragemnt in that i m  calling again fragmentsecond  which hold 4 tabs (e,p,t,s fragments)and 4 fragment so when I m in tab fragment i want to go mainfragment on back press but not when I am pressing back nothing happening.i.suppose in fragment soncond i m in pfragemnt. and when i back press i want to come in mainfragment

```
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    EFragment eFragment = new EFragment();
    eFragment.setArguments(bundle1);
    PFragment pFragment = new PFragment();
    pFragment.setArguments(bundle1);

    TFragment tFragment = new TFragment();
    tFragment.setArguments(bundle1);

    SFragment sFragment = new SFragment();
    sFragment.setArguments(bundle1);

    adapter.addFrag(eFragment, E_FRAGMENT);
    adapter.addFrag(pFragment, P_FRAGMENT);
    adapter.addFrag(tFragment, T_FRAGMENT);
    adapter.addFrag(sFragment, S_FRAGMENT);

    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below statement while calling tabfragment..

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.add(R.id.Container, new TabFragment());
 transaction.addToBackStack("TabFragment");
 transaction.commit();
```

and in MainActivity override onBackPressed method and write below statement..

```
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: this is same i m calling and same i m handling

Comment: i m asking about tab layout

Comment: i m in one fragemnt which have button  onclick of that button again calling one fragment which have 4 tabs

Comment: i want to go 1 fragemnt which have button

Comment: transaction.addToBackStack("TabFragment");  i cant add in tabs

Comment: have you write `addToBackStack()` while calling tabfragment from mainFragment?

Comment: fragmentsecond = new Fragmentsecond ();
                    fragmentsecond .setArguments(bundle1);
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame, fragmentsecond , TAG_EVENT_FRAGMENT)
                            .addToBackStack("mainfragment")
                            .commit();

Answer (score 0):

You need to overide the android onBackPressed method:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //write your fragment switching code here.
    }
```

Comment: that is not answer this is just back press method.that everybody khows

Comment: i want to come from tabs fragment

Comment: So whats the problem override the onBackPressed method in whichever activity you have written your above pasted code. It'll take you back to your oneFragment with the button.

Comment: already written  this and working for all fragment but i m fragment calling again fragment which have 4 tabs

Comment: from tabs  i want to come

Answer (score 0):

i m handling this in back press on activity

```
 onbackpress(){
Fragment second=  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragemntsecond");

   if (event != null && event.isVisible()) {


            mainfragment mainfragment = new mainfragment ();
            this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame, mainfragment , "mainfragment ")
                    .commit();
        }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

See if this helps, by this you can go to tab 1 from any tab selected instead of tab 1

I have used Tab layout as you did same and also used ViewPager,

i have did this in `onBackPressed` method of my activity where i have set tablayout

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() > 0) {
        //if any tab selected instead of tab 1
        mDoubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    } else if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        //if tab 1 selected
        mDoubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        if (mDoubleBackToExitPressedOnce)
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);//go to tab 1
}
```

`mViewPager` is global variable of ViewPager

By `mViewPager.getCurrentItem()` you will get current tab selected in ViewPager
doesn't matter if you have swiped or selected any tab by clicking on the tab it will return current tab position

> **Explanation**

**in `onBackPressed` method of activity**

> **1st Step In `if`condition**

I have checked if any Tab is selected other then Tab 1

if so then will set boolean value to false

> **2nd Step in `else if` condition**

I have checked if Tab 1 is selected

if so then set boolean value to true

and then in `if` condition check if that boolean value is true or not, if its true then `super.onBackPressed();`  is called

> **3rd Step out of if else condition**

write `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);` by this you will be switched to directly Tab 1 from any Tab other then Tab 1

> **Purpose of doing this is**

if You are in any other Tab other then Tab 1 and if you press back button in phone, Tab 1 will be selected

And if you are in Tab 1 and you Press back button in phone then app will be closed i.e. `super.onBackPressed();` will be called

> **Live Example of this is whatsapp tab of Chat, Status and Call**

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers to other Stack Exchange questions. Instead, include the essential portions of the answer here, and *tailor the answer to this specific question.*

Comment: @Mogsdad ok will not use it again, bt if i have answered any question earlier and i answer it same then my answer will be deleted, i did it early but he said don't post answer same as early did instead leave a link to that answer so i leaved a link to that answer here

Comment: If your answer can't be tailored to the question, and really does answer it, then it's possible that the questions are [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). In that case, you should flag or vote the duplicate, which will help future users find their answers.